# Is there a browser which still supports "file:///" links

Tags: file, browser, hyperlink, opensearch

I tried to use http://www.opensearchserver.com/ to index our Intranet file directory. That works fine. The Problem is, that the search result shows file:/// links, which are not supported by all modern web browser (maybe for security reasons).

For my Intranet I do not need this file:/// link protection. I just want to click on this link to open the file.

Do you know any solution to this problem?

Comment: not sure what you are talking about. Firefox and Chrome support it just fine. Could you link to an article describing the security problems you are talking about?

Comment: If you open a webpage e.g. http : //page.html and this page contains a link to file:///data.pdf, the link to this file does not work

Comment: not for me. Created a test.html file with a <a href="file:///C:/somefile.pdf">test</a> and could click it without a problem.

Comment: upload this file to a web server and try to do the same again.

Comment: not going to unless you link some sort of article describing how this is a security risk or why/when it was disabled. To my knowledge, you won't find such an article. The problem isn't your browser. It's your server.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack#URI_encoded_directory_traversal for details on why it is usually disabled.

Answer (score 0):

If the created html file is file:// too, then it will work. 
if its an http:// page, links with file:// DO NOT work. 
on the newest browsers at least... IE7 should do it